# Use C++ iostream in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iostream

I have a class in C++ and the teacher said we have to use the program that came with the book. The book came with Visual Studio 98.  I can not get it to work with my Windows 8 laptop. Is there a way that I can use Visual Studio 2010 to do the work.  I have added the directory to the project but it still does not want to use the iostream file.  I even added "using namespace std;" to it and I still get an error for it.  Any help will be appreciated.

I would like to thank everyone for their help. I have a working platform now thanks to all of you.  I just added "#include "stdafx.h", "using namespace std;", disabled precompiled header files, and pointed the project to the folder with header files.  I am going to try to bring up the issue of out of date course to someone who will listen but I have a felling that it will fall on deaf ears like it has before.

Comment: Could you provide the program? And do you mean it won't open a file that you're trying to open? That doesn't always use the same directory  as the executable.

Comment: The program works till I try to run the code. It will compile it.  I get a "error spawning cl.exe" every time.  This is the code that was given to me and was told it should work.                                 #include <iostream.h>

int main( )
{
 cout << "*****"             << endl;
 cout << "*      *     *"    << endl;
 cout << "*     ***   ***"   << endl;
 cout << "*      *     *"    << endl;
 cout << "*****"             << endl;

 return 0;
}

Comment: `#include <iostream.h>` shouldn't work because it's an old header that isn't part of standard C++. Anyway, there are some topics on this on Google. The course honestly shouldn't be forcing you to use outdated headers.

Comment: That was the original code that was given to me. I modify it to "#include <iostream>" then next line I put "using namespace std;". From what I have read thats all I needed to do. Is there more that I am missing.

Comment: I was just pointing it out. The error looks to mean it's having problems running the compiler.

Comment: I would rather do it the way it should be done but the instructor says we have to use a book that is more than a decade old. So is there anything that you can think of for me to try?

Comment: I suggest trying what you find [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=visual+studio+2010error+spawning+cl.exe&oq=visual+studio+2010error+spawning+cl.exe&aqs=chrome.0.57j0.9297j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=visual+studio+2010+error+spawning+cl.exe&spell=1&sa=X&ei=ZwG1UeWAAqrXyAGdooCwCQ&ved=0CC0QBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.aWc&fp=5e78e60d1f8c5cef&biw=944&bih=937). It looks like there are quite a few suggestions.

Comment: You should point out to the instructor that the example you are trying to compile has non-standard C++, so it is pretty useless because it won't work on many compilers. Certainly not on any recent ones.

Comment: Send him here and tell him to post a defense for using such an old book. That is unacceptable.

Comment: Point your instructor to:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984818(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I brought up the issue but she is the department chair so I'm pretty much SOL on the issue cause she knows everything and nothing ever goes wrong with her courses.

Comment: She says that the newer versions of studio do all the work for yea and you don't have to know c++ to work in it. If it was up to me I would boot her ass out.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to fix the wrong problem. Academics in all fields tend to teach the same courses year after year. They teach what they learnt (side comment, the spell checker does not know that learnt is the past tense of learn, thinks it should be learned:)  when they were students because that was clearly successful (it led them to where they are now). Even with more traditional subjects this is flawed but with the newer technologies it is fatally flawed.

Note that in order to maintain that nothing has changed in C++ since Visual Studio 98 (whose C++ implementation is - necessarily - prior to the 1998 C++ Standard) the teacher effectively admits that s/he has learnt nothing about C++ since it was first standardized in 1998. You and your fellow students did not sign up (and spend your money) to learn an ancient dialect of pre-standard C++.

As an individual you will be unable to do anything in a face-of with the department of which the teacher is a member. In order to bring about change you will need to band together and get your entire class to take action. The question then will be how politically astute you can manage to be. Publicly denouncing the teacher and the department is unlikely to be the best first step, though keeping that as an option is probably part of a good plan of action.

BTW, if the course is about C++ then it should not be relying on a single proprietorial implementation, most especially one that is frozen 15 years in the past.

A final comment. As of Windows 7 Microsoft stopped supporting 16-bit based code and only provides emulators for earlier 32-bit versions of Windows (which do support 16-bit software)in the Professional version. Because I have a number of 16-bit utility programs supporting my teaching  the game of Bridge I had to upgrade to Windows 7 Professional for continued use of these programs. I strongly suspect that the runtimes and the libraries that come with Visual Studio 98 will have fundamental problems if you attempt to run them on Windows 8.

Best wishes for a successful outcome

Francis

Comment: I have tried to get other students to ban together but its hard to get kids these days to do anything that might disrupt their video games.  I have tried it before and it was an epic failure. Is there a official website for C++ standards that is used by majority of programmers? I want to get my ammo inline before I take this head on with higher powers to be. I do not approve of out of date courses be used cause its a waste of money and its setting the students up for failure.

Comment: There are quite a few websites for C++ but the most official of them is http://www.isocpp.org/

Answer (score 0):

As a quick temporary fix you can create a file named `iostream.h` with this content:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

and that will likely fix most of the book examples.

However, just as others pointed out, you're in an unfair situation, and if you can, might try to improve it.  If the class is called 'C++' and you pay for it, the institution is shipping you corrupt goods.  File for refund or fix.  You can win a lawsuit if it comes to that.  I guess boss of the instructor would not be happy about that, and could be motivated.

If the class is called something like history of programming, and it's actually mandatory to use the prescribed tools, ask help from the institution to set up the walking history on your laptop. (actually I expect it to work fine, it definitely worked on XP, so in corner case you can set it up in the XP compatibility thing).   Ask help of the ombudsman if you get stuck.

If it's just some random WTF lecture, you're out of luck.

Comment: I have ask the helpdesk of the school for help and they said that they do not support the program cause of the security issues with it. They will not allow the program to be installed on their computers. The instructor told me that nothing in C++ has changed since the book was published in 1998 so the class does not need to be changed.

Comment: Great, that statement alone can be used to eject that instructor for incompetency. And the fact that he tries to force use of software the school helpdesk considers risk is good for action on different grounds.

Comment: Kinda hard to get a department chair eject. I've been bumping heads with her since I started there.

Comment: Your instructor might like to take a look at http://developerfocus.com/kurskalenderoversikt.aspx?cat=1052&id=170382&kursid=178077

Answer (score 0):

This works in Visual Studio 2010 and frankly should in any modern C++ compiler.  It's copied from your comment above, and modified for modern C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "**" << endl;
    cout << " * " << endl;
    cout << " *** **" << endl;
    cout << " * " << endl;
    cout << "**" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, you probably have VS2010 installed incorrectly.  Do you still see "error spawning cl.exe"?

Comment: Its the older version of studio that gives the spawning cl.exe error. The newer version (studio 2010) gives the following error "warning C4627:'#include<iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use".

Comment: That was not clear from your question.  When you created the project there was an option to use precompiled headers.  Don't check that.  Alternatively, just place `#include "stdafx.h"` as the first line of the program.  It should already exist in the project if you enabled precompiled headers.

Comment: Sorry about the question not being clear, I should have known better to write it when I was so angry. Thnx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, edit your project's properties and turn off precompiled headers.

Comment: This actually is the solution I believe...In fact do this right when you create the project...

Comment: And you seriously think that turning off pch will magically create a file named iostream.h, that is not shipped with vs2010 RTL?

Comment: @BalogPal it will get rid of warning C4627 though